# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onAfterDeleteRow')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am facing this error when trying to get the `_id` although it is coming but still it is providing the error of being `undefined`. Now upon deleting it is coming with this error. Thanks in advance!

```
const columns = [
  {
    dataField: "sl.no",
    text: "S No.",
    formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
      return rowIndex + 1;
    },
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "name",
    text: "Name",
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "tag",
    text: "Tag",
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "_id",
    text: "No. Of Questsions",
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row) => {
      return <div className="text-center">{row.questions.length}</div>;
    },
  },
  {
    dataField: "technical_weightage",
    text: "Tech Weightage",
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "soft_weightage",
    text: "Soft Weightage",
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "gender",
    text: "Gender",
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "id",
    isDummyField: true,
    classes: "delete-container",
    sort: false,
    headerStyle: () => {
      return {
        width: "60px",
      };
    },
    formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
      return (
        <button
          className="deleteBtn"
          style={{
            border: "none",
            background: "none",
          }}
          onClick={() => this.onAfterDeleteRow(row._id)}
        >
          <DeleteIcon />
        </button>
      );
    },
  },
];

class EditableTables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breadcrumbItems: [
        { title: "Interview App", link: "#" },
        { title: "Questions", link: "#" },
      ],
      interviews: [],
    };
  }

  onAfterDeleteRow = (rowId) => {
    this.props.interviewDelete(rowId);
    // this.props.interviewDelete(
    // (selectedRow) => {
    //     let newRows = selectedRow.filter((row) => row.interval !== rowId);
    //     newRows = newRows.map((row, index) => ({ ...row, interval: index }));
    //     return [...newRows];
    //   },
    // );
    // return false;
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("this.props.Interviews", this.props.Interviews);
    await this.props.getAllInterviews(this.props.user._id);

    await this.setState({ interviews: [...this.props.Interviews] });
    console.log("this.state.interviews", this.state.interviews);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="page-content">
          <Container fluid>
            {/* <Breadcrumbs title="Interviews" /> */}

            <Row>
              <Col xs={12}>
                <Card>
                  <CardBody>
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                      <BootstrapTable
                        keyField="id"
                        data={this.state.interviews}
                        columns={columns}
                        cellEdit={cellEditFactory({ mode: "click" })}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("state", state);
  return {
    user: state.auth.user,
    Interviews: state.interview.interviews.response,
  };
};
```

[image]

Comment: The value of `this` inside `formatter` doesn't have access to the class instance.

Comment: so how that function can be called then?

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you are using `columns` and `formatter`, but you would need to pass the class instance or the `onAfterDeleteRow` function to the `formatter` for it to work.  Without a more complete example, I can't help more than that.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mark Skelton said, the `columns` variable defined outside the React class component, `this.onAfterDeleteRow` throws that error, because `this` context is not the instance of the React class component.

You can try to define the constant columns outside the component, extend the constant columns with the columns those need to access the `props` or instance methods.

E.g.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';

const columns = [
  { dataField: 'sl.no', text: 'S No.', formatter: (_, __, rowIndex) => rowIndex + 1, sort: true },
  { dataField: 'name', text: 'Name', sort: true },
  { dataField: 'tag', text: 'Tag', sort: true },
  {
    dataField: '_id',
    text: 'No. Of Questsions',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (_, row) => <div className="text-center">{row.questions.length}</div>,
  },
  { dataField: 'technical_weightage', text: 'Tech Weightage', sort: true },
  { dataField: 'soft_weightage', text: 'Soft Weightage', sort: true },
  { dataField: 'gender', text: 'Gender', sort: true },
];

class EditableTables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breadcrumbItems: [
        { title: 'Interview App', link: '#' },
        { title: 'Questions', link: '#' },
      ],
      interviews: [],
    };
  }

  onAfterDeleteRow = (rowId) => {};

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.getAllInterviews(this.props.user._id);
    await this.setState({ interviews: [...this.props.Interviews] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="page-content">
          <Container fluid>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={12}>
                <Card>
                  <CardBody>
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                      <BootstrapTable
                        keyField="id"
                        data={this.state.interviews}
                        columns={[
                          ...columns,
                          {
                            dataField: 'id',
                            isDummyField: true,
                            classes: 'delete-container',
                            sort: false,
                            headerStyle: () => {
                              return {
                                width: '60px',
                              };
                            },
                            formatter: (_, row) => {
                              return (
                                <button
                                  className="deleteBtn"
                                  style={{
                                    border: 'none',
                                    background: 'none',
                                  }}
                                  onClick={() => this.onAfterDeleteRow(row._id)}
                                >
                                  <DeleteIcon />
                                </button>
                              );
                            },
                          },
                        ]}
                        cellEdit={cellEditFactory({ mode: 'click' })}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```